# finding duplicate rows on more than one field

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I am using this query to find duplicates based on two fields:

```
SELECT 
    last_name, 
    first_name,
    middle_initial,
    COUNT(last_name) AS Duplicates,
    IF(rec_id = '', 1, 0) AS has_REC_ID 
FROM files
GROUP BY last_name, first_name
HAVING COUNT(last_name) > 1 AND COUNT(first_name) > 1;
```

Okay, what this returns is a set of rows with first, last, and middle names, a column called 'Duplicates' with a lot of 2s, and a column called has_REC_ID with mixed 1s and 0s.

Ultimately, what I'm trying to do is find which rows have matching first and last names--and then for each of those pairs, find the one that has ('') as a value for `rec_id`, assign the rec_id value from the one that DOES have a rec_id, and then delete the record that had a rec_id in the first place.

So for starters I though I would create a new column and do something like this:

```
UPDATE files a 
SET a.has_dup    --new column
    = if(a.last_name IN (
                         SELECT b.last_name
                         FROM files b
                         GROUP BY b.last_name 
                         HAVING COUNT(b.last_name) > 1
                        )
      , 1, null);
```

But MySQL returns: "You can't specify target table 'a' for update in from clause"

I'll bet there's something much less ridiculous than the method I'm trying here. Can someone please help me figure out what that is?

UPDATE: I also tried:

```
UPDATE files a 
SET a.has_dup = 1
WHERE a.last_name IN (
                         SELECT b.last_name
                         FROM files b
                         GROUP BY b.last_name 
                         HAVING COUNT(b.last_name) > 1
                     );
```

...and got the same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could:

1) Create a holding table

2) Populate the holding table with those rows that have a matching first and last name and have rec_id != ""

3) Delete the rows from the original table (files) that have a matching first and last name and have rec_id != ""

4) Update the rows in the original table that have a matching first and last name and have rec_id = "".

5) Drop the holding table

So something like:

```
create table temp
(
firstname varchar(100) not null,
lastname varchar(100) not null,
rec_id int not null
);


insert into temp (select firstname,lastname,rec_id from files where firstname =    lastname and rec_id != '');


delete from files where firstname = lastname and rec_id != '';

update files f
set f.rec_id = (select t.rec_id from temp t where f.firstname = t.firstname and f.lastname = t.lastname)
where f.firstname = f.lastname 
and f.rec_id != '';


drop table temp;
```

Comment: Yes, something along these lines should be very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html):

> Currently, you cannot update a table and select from the same table in a subquery.

I can't think of a quick workaround to that.

---

#### Update

Apparently, [there *is* a "quick" workaround](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/23/how-to-select-from-an-update-target-in-mysql/), but whether or not it's performant is another issue. It's all about adding a new layer of indirection by introducing a temporary table:

```
UPDATE files a 
SET a.has_dup    --new column
    = if(a.last_name IN (
                     SELECT b.last_name
                     FROM
                          (SELECT * FROM files)      -- new table target
                     b
                     GROUP BY b.last_name 
                     HAVING COUNT(b.last_name) > 1
                    ),
      1, null);
```

Comment: well that would explain it. However, a quick workaround might be to select into another table called something else, right?

Comment: @tjb1982: For starters, one that doesn't involve copying all your data into a second, duplicate table. :)

Answer (score -1):

I don't have any MySQL to test, but this I think this should be work: (EDITED->FAIL)

```
UPDATE files
SET has_dup
    = if(last_name IN (
                         SELECT b.last_name
                         FROM files b
                         GROUP BY b.last_name 
                         HAVING COUNT(b.last_name) > 1
                      )
      , 1, null);
```

EDITED: Another try:

```
UPDATE files f, (SELECT b.last_name
                   FROM files b
               GROUP BY b.last_name 
                 HAVING COUNT(b.last_name) > 1
                ) as duplicates
   SET f.has_dup = 1
 WHERE f.last_name = duplicates.last_name
```

Comment: Nope. Thanks, but now the message is: "You can't specify the target table 'files' for update in from clause'

Comment: @tjb1982 Sorry, check the second one. (Should I add another solution or edit the wrong solution?)

Comment: I didn't vote this down, but see Tomalak's answer as to this not being the right tack to take re: the documentation.

Comment: @tjb1982 Seems there is a workaround to that: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/23/how-to-select-from-an-update-target-in-mysql/